# How do I ask about availability of a certain class of software on Ubuntu?

Tags: discussion

**Generic part**:

I would like to learn about the applications that exist in a certain class of software on Ubuntu. But asking a question like that is a software recommendation and is against the rules of Ask Ubuntu. Is there a way to ask a question about that on Ask Ubuntu in a way that will follow the rules of the site and be useful and informative for others in the long term?

**Specific part**:

I would like to learn about drawing and painting software that is available on Ubuntu, or may become available soon (I believe there isn't much today; is there any hope for the better?). I'd like to use Ubuntu on [Microsoft Surface Pro](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Surface_Pro_2) line of tablet/laptops and draw on it.

This class of software I have in mind includes tools such as:

- [Adobe_Photoshop](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adobe_Photoshop)
- [Paint Tool SAI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SAI_%28software%29)
- [Manga Studio](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manga_Studio)

All of which are not available o Linux.

Comment: Can I just ask where you got the info "a software recommendation and is against the rules of Ask Ubuntu"?